# How to write this interpolate function using OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, interpolation

I want to optimize [this](https://github.com/perdoch/hesaff/blob/master/helpers.cpp) code, in particular this function:

```
bool interpolate(const Mat &im, float ofsx, float ofsy, float a11, float a12, float a21, float a22, Mat &res)
{         
   bool ret = false;
   // input size (-1 for the safe bilinear interpolation)
   const int width = im.cols-1;
   const int height = im.rows-1;
   // output size
   const int halfWidth  = res.cols >> 1;
   const int halfHeight = res.rows >> 1;
   int dim = res.rows * res.cols;
   float *out = res.ptr<float>(0);
   for (int j=-halfHeight; j<=halfHeight; ++j)
   {
      const float rx = ofsx + j * a12;
      const float ry = ofsy + j * a22;
      #pragma omp simd
      for(int i=-halfWidth; i<=halfWidth; ++i)
      {
         float wx = rx + i * a11;
         float wy = ry + i * a21;
         const int x = (int) floor(wx);
         const int y = (int) floor(wy);
         if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height)
         {
            // compute weights
            wx -= x; wy -= y;
            // bilinear interpolation
            *out++ = 
               (1.0f - wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * im.at<float>(y,x)   + wx * im.at<float>(y,x+1)) +
               (       wy) * ((1.0f - wx) * im.at<float>(y+1,x) + wx * im.at<float>(y+1,x+1));
         } else {
            *out++ = 0;
            ret =  true; // touching boundary of the input            
         }
      }
   }
   return ret;
}
```

Can anybody please help to find an equivalent function in OpenCV for the code above? I'm not expert on image processing, so I don't really know what the fucntion above does in details, but I think this is a warp-affine transformation, even though I don't really know how to define an OpenCV equivalent.

It seems that the input images are the blurred image, the original image or small patches of it. The output result is always a small patch.

Here are some samples:

**Sample 1:**

Args:

```
ofx=175.497 ofsy=315.06 a11=1.69477 a12=0.0671724 a21=0.0679493 a22=1.56309
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

**Sample 2:**

Args:

```
ofx=572.121 ofsy=326.659 a11=0.871508 a12=0 a21=0.346405 a22=1.14744
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

**Sample 3:**

```
ofx=66.571 ofsy=148.991 a11=1.12027 a12=0.126609 a21=0.126609 a22=2.53436
```

Input image:

[image]

Output image:

[image]

These are different sections of the original code where the function is called:

```
  // warp input according to current shape matrix
  interpolate(wrapper.prevBlur, lx, ly, u11*ratio, u12*ratio, u21*ratio, u22*ratio, img);

  Mat smoothed(patchImageSize, patchImageSize, CV_32FC1, (void *)&workspace.front());
  // interpolate with det == 1
  if (!interpolate(img, x, y, a11, a12, a21, a22, smoothed))
  {

  // subsample with corresponding scale
  interpolate(smoothed, (float)(patchImageSize>>1), (float)(patchImageSize>>1), imageToPatchScale, 0, 0, imageToPatchScale, patch);


  // ok, do the interpolation
  interpolate(img, x, y, a11, a12, a21, a22, patch);
```

This is what happens when I try to use `warpAffine` in the following way:

```
  // warp input according to current shape matrix
  interpolate(wrapper.prevBlur, lx, ly, u11*ratio, u12*ratio, u21*ratio, u22*ratio, img);

  Mat warp_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
  Mat myPatch(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC1);
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,2) = lx;
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,2) = ly;
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,0) = u11*ratio;
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,1) = u12*ratio;
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,0) = u21*ratio;
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,1) = u22*ratio;

  warpAffine(wrapper.prevBlur, myPatch, warp_mat, myPatch.size());
```

The resulting `myPatch` matrix is a zero matrix, while `img` (obtained by `interpolate`) is:

```
[19.109245, 19.189388, 18.941183, 18.454611, 18.285404, 19.447983, 22.037096, 28.504759, 37.753605, 50.69936, 61.34388, 67.619637, 70.699326, 71.640556, 73.347702, 72.383781, 70.7649, 72.320709, 74.32235;
 18.464636, 18.408369, 18.347059, 18.194805, 17.982847, 18.312258, 18.990305, 21.852564, 26.399525, 35.10569, 44.444019, 53.986103, 59.851856, 63.937149, 67.766968, 70.979973, 73.074722, 77.097763, 82.344398;
 17.838448, 17.706562, 17.580456, 17.869242, 18.216852, 18.72654, 19.004158, 20.150208, 21.66539, 26.167187, 31.805283, 41.04277, 48.207466, 54.719109, 59.793156, 65.378006, 71.004974, 77.016037, 86.317352;
 17.257101, 17.117496, 16.95055, 17.34347, 18.505379, 20.129673, 21.161978, 22.195414, 22.287436, 24.150574, 26.179817, 32.619934, 39.298115, 46.696926, 52.091522, 57.986988, 64.629898, 72.434052, 82.955505;
 16.810595, 16.665813, 16.672272, 17.16098, 18.665346, 21.783976, 24.785789, 27.150511, 27.23918, 27.834826, 27.594404, 30.645121, 35.405987, 42.133587, 46.915634, 51.880707, 57.028702, 64.57579, 74.402069;
 16.687065, 16.451401, 16.626608, 17.460049, 19.36956, 23.552647, 28.802736, 33.788773, 35.505379, 35.85894, 34.729523, 34.880505, 37.088661, 42.075432, 45.702, 49.056709, 51.509052, 56.637093, 63.660839;
 16.802176, 16.594761, 16.863697, 18.126085, 20.491119, 25.517574, 32.737259, 40.572498, 45.324429, 46.528313, 45.586109, 44.153858, 43.667118, 46.450905, 48.539593, 50.182858, 50.18359, 51.575584, 54.267056;
 17.036257, 17.025221, 17.271259, 18.925261, 22.124079, 27.620583, 35.921772, 46.177872, 54.232437, 57.583233, 57.648571, 55.857315, 53.885891, 54.148857, 55.00872, 54.9893, 52.946201, 50.873283, 49.034798;
 17.337849, 17.61212, 18.028404, 19.572941, 23.455297, 29.841951, 38.668663, 49.819805, 60.617371, 66.327873, 68.025574, 66.935631, 64.995117, 63.513988, 63.28405, 62.325748, 58.940784, 53.796066, 48.033508;
 17.798275, 18.203262, 19.018663, 20.718761, 24.611408, 31.378065, 40.706932, 51.637016, 63.323963, 71.373169, 74.578476, 74.412659, 74.106857, 72.411026, 71.710922, 70.007111, 66.181709, 58.721882, 50.149853;
 18.593805, 19.017687, 20.172789, 22.093014, 25.971659, 32.813194, 41.989246, 52.252911, 62.929924, 71.418938, 76.355003, 77.044289, 78.709656, 78.83432, 78.581551, 76.614075, 72.71788, 63.598377, 52.698578;
 19.567734, 20.197411, 21.640959, 24.039509, 27.603041, 34.091061, 42.821777, 52.127884, 61.030842, 68.610733, 73.860558, 75.530617, 78.25412, 81.30085, 82.840904, 80.822067, 76.685196, 67.430412, 54.54921;
 21.115396, 21.835562, 23.40497, 26.244884, 30.036913, 35.568745, 43.308716, 51.656746, 58.69318, 64.595673, 69.845467, 72.11985, 74.878944, 79.890228, 83.964821, 82.866249, 77.71666, 68.196243, 55.256557;
 23.264105, 24.024746, 25.705564, 28.513554, 32.514004, 37.26601, 43.47644, 50.611153, 56.786697, 61.13575, 66.052094, 69.762238, 71.692001, 76.810669, 81.848129, 82.157066, 76.844963, 66.500725, 54.042095;
 26.102678, 26.758638, 28.201065, 30.806498, 34.584103, 38.752495, 43.416939, 48.890656, 54.433743, 58.482693, 63.515507, 69.373245, 71.917755, 74.965172, 78.791039, 79.034378, 73.354454, 62.917992, 50.983219;
 29.008026, 30.016344, 30.787025, 32.692429, 35.850079, 39.365425, 42.956245, 46.993965, 51.688225, 56.120068, 61.624519, 69.804024, 74.923134, 76.170395, 76.252747, 74.715118, 68.599701, 58.000847, 47.082359;
 31.630077, 33.315144, 33.247631, 33.903202, 36.094364, 38.939133, 42.000217, 45.338474, 49.197887, 53.639317, 59.658398, 69.140472, 77.870468, 79.725624, 75.932251, 69.885872, 62.522583, 52.486378, 42.571148;
 34.113537, 36.435402, 35.544792, 34.225368, 35.189747, 37.445477, 40.579632, 44.427345, 48.191299, 52.085419, 57.660496, 66.887024, 77.807755, 81.70005, 76.676743, 66.486168, 56.192219, 46.825108, 38.276539;
 37.42725, 39.82682, 37.698589, 34.016525, 33.155304, 35.16758, 39.039139, 44.336964, 49.359722, 52.590809, 56.610603, 64.08419, 74.419289, 80.603294, 76.006302, 63.653465, 50.843102, 41.247444, 34.471062]
```

Update after comment:

These are results by using `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]` with the following code:

```
  Mat warp_mat( 2, 3, CV_32FC1 );
  Mat myPatch(img.rows, img.cols, CV_32FC1);
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,0) = 1;                  //u11*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,1) = 0;                  //u12*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,2) = 0+(img.cols >> 1);  //lx
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,0) = 0;                  //u21*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,1) = 1;                  //u22*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,2) = 0+(img.rows >> 1);  //ly

  warpAffine(wrapper.prevBlur, myPatch, warp_mat, myPatch.size());

  interpolate(wrapper.prevBlur, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, img);

  std::cout<<"img="<<std::endl<<img<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<"myPatch="<<std::endl<<myPatch<<std::endl;
```

The result is the same, but if I try to use:

```
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,0) = 1;                  //u11*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,1) = 1;                  //u12*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,2) = 0+(img.cols >> 1);  //lx
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,0) = 0;                  //u21*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,1) = 1;                  //u22*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,2) = 0+(img.rows >> 1);  //ly

  warpAffine(wrapper.prevBlur, myPatch, warp_mat, myPatch.size());

  interpolate(wrapper.prevBlur, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, img);
```

The matrix are "mirrored":

```
myPatch=
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4431293, 2.1086276, 1.7749974, 1.5721301, 1.5403291, 1.6410155, 1.8406107, 2.1113796, 2.3246853, 2.274801;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3276107, 2.0702307, 1.8100098, 1.6615094, 1.6572961, 1.7410251, 1.8701531, 2.0462515, 2.1933937;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3676813, 2.1666555, 1.9666147, 1.8710723, 1.9005303, 1.9753534, 2.0355756, 2.1005828;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4378726, 2.2967758, 2.1802788, 2.1628339, 2.2288194, 2.2786529, 2.2584724;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3656359, 2.3085568, 2.3188434, 2.4140301, 2.513881, 2.5077794;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.206573, 2.20857, 2.3185263, 2.5056028, 2.6312659;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1686711, 2.1401191, 2.2343175, 2.4260342;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3495517, 2.2178252, 2.1930335;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.6443374, 2.4216607;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.8480706]
img=
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4431293, 2.1086276, 1.7749974, 1.5721301, 1.5403291, 1.6410155, 1.8406107, 2.1113796, 2.3246853, 2.274801;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3276107, 2.0702307, 1.8100098, 1.6615094, 1.6572961, 1.7410251, 1.8701531, 2.0462515, 2.1933937, 2.1447542, 1.8548106;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3676813, 2.1666555, 1.9666147, 1.8710723, 1.9005303, 1.9753534, 2.0355756, 2.1005828, 2.1541297, 2.0949042, 1.8804716, 1.6108752;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4378726, 2.2967758, 2.1802788, 2.1628339, 2.2288194, 2.2786529, 2.2584724, 2.2164674, 2.1899939, 2.1344388, 2.0028977, 1.8055484, 1.6097167;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3656359, 2.3085568, 2.3188434, 2.4140301, 2.513881, 2.5077794, 2.3889487, 2.2654738, 2.21731, 2.2129889, 2.1711345, 2.027447, 1.7903067, 1.5879864;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.206573, 2.20857, 2.3185263, 2.5056028, 2.6312659, 2.5770819, 2.3866575, 2.2314539, 2.2230167, 2.3092971, 2.3504019, 2.2321868, 1.9485472, 1.637617, 1.494508;
 0, 0, 0, 2.1686711, 2.1401191, 2.2343175, 2.4260342, 2.566293, 2.5228219, 2.3388758, 2.2057574, 2.2558136, 2.4211838, 2.5120842, 2.3888607, 2.0588915, 1.6645602, 1.4044838, 1.4204007;
 0, 0, 2.3495517, 2.2178252, 2.1930335, 2.3035395, 2.4375367, 2.446404, 2.3236551, 2.2328601, 2.3145993, 2.5046468, 2.5949829, 2.4436085, 2.0789487, 1.6472976, 1.3386253, 1.3225981, 1.6233296;
 0, 2.6443374, 2.4216607, 2.271126, 2.2733064, 2.367074, 2.4035037, 2.3307135, 2.2715025, 2.3534446, 2.5142543, 2.558598, 2.3710468, 2.0039113, 1.6069642, 1.3526549, 1.3859948, 1.7268054, 2.1843567;
 2.8480706, 2.6081781, 2.4022317, 2.3262172, 2.3576505, 2.3759208, 2.3233094, 2.2885542, 2.3600159, 2.4632583, 2.4390275, 2.2265964, 1.9053584, 1.6181513, 1.4964664, 1.6123655, 1.9332824, 2.2962041, 2.4815767]
```

And finally using:

```
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,0) = 0;                  //u11*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,1) = 1;                  //u22*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(0,2) = 0+(img.cols >> 1);  //lx
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,0) = 1;                  //u21*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,1) = 1;                  //u22*ratio
  warp_mat.at<float>(1,2) = 0+(img.rows >> 1);  //ly
```

I get:

```
myPatch=
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4431293, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1086276, 2.3276107, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7749974, 2.0702307, 2.3676813, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5721301, 1.8100098, 2.1666555, 2.4378726, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5403291, 1.6615094, 1.9666147, 2.2967758, 2.3656359, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6410155, 1.6572961, 1.8710723, 2.1802788, 2.3085568, 2.206573, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.8406107, 1.7410251, 1.9005303, 2.1628339, 2.3188434, 2.20857, 2.1686711, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1113796, 1.8701531, 1.9753534, 2.2288194, 2.4140301, 2.3185263, 2.1401191, 2.3495517, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.3246853, 2.0462515, 2.0355756, 2.2786529, 2.513881, 2.5056028, 2.2343175, 2.2178252, 2.6443374, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.274801, 2.1933937, 2.1005828, 2.2584724, 2.5077794, 2.6312659, 2.4260342, 2.1930335, 2.4216607, 2.8480706]
img=
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.4431293, 2.3276107, 2.3676813, 2.4378726, 2.3656359, 2.206573, 2.1686711, 2.3495517, 2.6443374, 2.8480706;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.1086276, 2.0702307, 2.1666555, 2.2967758, 2.3085568, 2.20857, 2.1401191, 2.2178252, 2.4216607, 2.6081781, 2.6495261;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.7749974, 1.8100098, 1.9666147, 2.1802788, 2.3188434, 2.3185263, 2.2343175, 2.1930335, 2.271126, 2.4022317, 2.4685297, 2.4485474;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5721301, 1.6615094, 1.8710723, 2.1628339, 2.4140301, 2.5056028, 2.4260342, 2.3035395, 2.2733064, 2.3262172, 2.3705757, 2.3652363, 2.3247712;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.5403291, 1.6572961, 1.9005303, 2.2288194, 2.513881, 2.6312659, 2.566293, 2.4375367, 2.367074, 2.3576505, 2.3551981, 2.3311026, 2.2715149, 2.1814501;
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.6410155, 1.7410251, 1.9753534, 2.2786529, 2.5077794, 2.5770819, 2.5228219, 2.446404, 2.4035037, 2.3759208, 2.3474753, 2.3124287, 2.240618, 2.1282687, 2.0381868;
 0, 0, 0, 1.8406107, 1.8701531, 2.0355756, 2.2584724, 2.3889487, 2.3866575, 2.3388758, 2.3236551, 2.3307135, 2.3233094, 2.3084226, 2.2854021, 2.2117574, 2.088321, 1.9926676, 1.9839712;
 0, 0, 2.1113796, 2.0462515, 2.1005828, 2.2164674, 2.2654738, 2.2314539, 2.2057574, 2.2328601, 2.2715025, 2.2885542, 2.2938819, 2.2722201, 2.1820612, 2.0477793, 1.957217, 1.954851, 2.0058911;
 0, 2.3246853, 2.1933937, 2.1541297, 2.1899939, 2.21731, 2.2230167, 2.2558136, 2.3145993, 2.3534446, 2.3600159, 2.3450513, 2.2874477, 2.1686828, 2.0435023, 1.9943975, 2.0270162, 2.0777535, 2.1049571;
 2.274801, 2.1447542, 2.0949042, 2.1344388, 2.2129889, 2.3092971, 2.4211838, 2.5046468, 2.5142543, 2.4632583, 2.3841665, 2.2811179, 2.1669631, 2.1026075, 2.1358697, 2.2212756, 2.2625117, 2.2268343, 2.180846]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you basically answered yourself and it looks like a basic affine transformation.

The equivelent in OpenCV is [warpAffine](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga0203d9ee5fcd28d40dbc4a1ea4451983).
In the `flags` of the function you can give it any of the [InterpolationFlags](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121).

The transformation matrix `M` at your case will be:

```
[[a11, a12, ofsx],
 [a21, a22, ofsy]
```

The output size is also a parameter, dependes on your numbers.

And if you want to optimize it as you say, you can compile OpenCV with CUDA support and then you could use the GPU version of this function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tired to use `warpAffine` with bad results, could please give a look at my updated question? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Its hard for me to say what exactly is the problem, i guess something with the offset and size of output. Maybe try some sanity check like warpAffine with identity transformation: `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]`. Are you getting back the input image? then try adding only the rotation or only the offset and look what happens.

Comment: Thansk again for your suggestion. Check out the updated question: it seems that the `img[i+9,j+9] = myPatch[i,j]` , especially considering that `img.rows`=`myPatch.rows` = 18. It seeems like the `img` result (obtained by the `interpolate` function is "centered" w.r.t. `mypatch` (obatined bhy `warpAffine`) and surrounded by zeros! Why this happens and how to obtain the same result?

Comment: If I can solve this this would be crucial for my project, I don't know I could thank you if you help me solving this :D

Comment: it happens because `halfWidth` and `halfHeight`. There is no right and wrong here, just a matter of conventions. Not sure what is the current problem, but if you want exactly the same results like your `interpolation` function so just add to the offset half the width in x and half height in y.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment, but what do you mean by `x` and `y`? Could you please refer to the code above?

Comment: @DanMašek thanks for your clarification, but do I have to add half of the height/width of the source or of the destination image?

Comment: @EladJoseph Please give a look at the update: I successfully obtained the same result for `[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0]]` but not for the generalized form

Comment: @DanMašek if you could please give a look at the update? :)